# Price is not displaying properly with twig/timber in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I have a situation where my price is not displaying properly with twig/timber in WordPress so I have to variables set as :

`{% set salestax = toolprice * (taxrate | number_format / 100) %}`
and `{% set tooltotal = toolprice * (1 + taxrate | number_format / 100) %}`

I have everything outputting properly, but it will only display as **1575.5** instead of **1575.50**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig's `number_format` is a wrapper for PHP's [`number_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). Meaning you can pass 3 extra arguments: `decimals`,  'decimal_separator', `thousands_separator`

```html
{{ price | number_format(2) }} {# out : 100.50 #}
```

If you don't want to pass the `decimals` each time you can overwrite the default parameters of the filter by doing the following:

```php
<?php
    $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);
    $twig->getExtension(\Twig\Extension\CoreExtension::class)->setNumberFormat(3, '.', ',');
```

---

Extra note: You shouldn't be formatting numbers will doing calculations, only apply the filter on the final output, this to prevent rounding errors.

```html
{% set salestax = toolprice * taxrate  100 %}
{{ salestax | number_format(2) }}

{% set tooltotal = toolprice * (1 + taxrate) / 100 %}
{{ tooltotal|number_format(2) }}
```

Comment: Thanks again so much!! I also edited this as: `{% set salestax = toolprice * taxrate / 100 %}` and this to: `{% set tooltotal = toolprice * (100 + taxrate) / 100 %}` and works perfect!